# How can I convert a string into a Deque?

Tags: java, interface, linked-list, deque

Under class `NewDeque` I have a function `public Deque<Character> IntoDeque(String a)` where I have to take in an input as a `String` and the return value should be a `Deque`.

I'm struggling to understand what I have to write in order to achieve this. Here is my code so far:

```
public class NewDeque {
    public Deque<Character> IntoDeque(String a) {
        Deque<Character> L = new LinkedListDeque<>();
        for (int x = 0; x < a.length()-1; x++) {
             L.add(a[x]) + "";
        }
        return L;
    }
    }
```

I'm struggling to understand how to implement this as a Deque so, can anyone please help. Please provide explanations too since it would be good for me as well. Thank you.

Example input is `"Side"`,

the output should be `'s', 'i', 'd', 'e'`

Here are some extra files in case you might want to know where I got certain methods from

LinkedListDeque (as of now):

```
public class LinkedListDeque<T> extends LinkedList<T> implements Deque<T> {
```

Interface Deque:

```
interface Deque<T> {
    void addFirst(T items);
    void addLast(T items);
    String toString();
    void removeLast();
    void removeFirst();
    void get(int index);
    int size();
    boolean isEmpty();
}
```

Comment: LinkedList extended Deque already. Just new LinkedList, fill it and return it.

Comment: how do u fill it? I'm confused, can you please explain?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have used code to reference an array `a[x]` rather than character of the String which is `a.charAt(x)`, and ignored last character of the string.

```
Deque<Character> dq = new LinkedList<>();
for (int x = 0; x < a.length(); x++) {
    dq.add(a.charAt(x));
}
return dq;
```

It's not clear what you wanted to achieve by `+ ""`, remove it.